# How i know details about cakephp url referer?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

After login i always getting the referer ulr is same but the redirect url is not the one which i used. And the url on the url bar is hashed but not redirected to this after log in.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please read [How to ask Good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should share your code which you try, so that we can help you